# Session Storage not being retrieved on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, session-storage

I have a create-react-app and I'm storage some state inside of sessionStorage to persist some redux state during the user's session.

Everything works fine in Desktop browsers but while debugging on a mobile device inside of Safari or Chrome the state isn't be retrieved on refresh. This causes errors since the state is no longer there.

**Any idea why this would only happen on a mobile browser?**

This is how I'm saving and retrieving the state with sessionStorage:

```
export function saveToLocalStorage(state: AppState) {
    const hasUserProfileId =
        state.system.profile.id && state.system.profile.id !== '';
    try {
        if (hasUserProfileId) {
            const serializedState = JSON.stringify(state);
            sessionStorage.setItem('state', serializedState);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error saving state to local storage');
    }
}

function loadFromLocalStorage() {
    console.log('loadFromLocalStorage - 1');

    try {
        const serializedState = sessionStorage.getItem('state');

        if (serializedState === null) {
            return undefined;
        }
        return JSON.parse(serializedState);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error loading state from local storage');
        return undefined;
    }
}
```

its null when doing `const serializedState = sessionStorage.getItem('state');` so it returns `undefined`

```
if (serializedState === null) {
     return undefined;
 }
```

Comment: [Check for the mobile browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=sessionStorage).

Comment: take a look on that thread, it might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55743941/localstorage-works-on-desktop-but-not-mobile-ios-version-12-2

Comment: @LucasHenrique Thanks for sending that thread I was using `beforeunload`, which was not supported. I ended up using the `unload` event listener, which is supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using `beforeunload` event listener to save the state on refresh. This event handler wasn't supported for mobile browsers. Replacing it with `unload` worked.

```
window.addEventListener('unload', () => {
     saveToLocalStorage(store.getState());
});
```